# Replace double quotes inside json value using python

Tags: python, json, regex

jsonStr =  '{"name": "John"s Garage", "company": "ABC"}'

It is a string JSON.

Need to convert to

```
'{"name": "John\"s Garage", "company": "ABC"}'
```

or

remove the double quotes entirely

```
'{"name": "Johns Garage", "company": "ABC"}'

import re
re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]\"[a-zA-Z]', '', )
```

This does not give desired reuslt

Comment: Is that the one and only example? Because you could just do a search and replace on `John"s Garage`. If it's not the only example, then you need to describe more clearly what, exactly, the inputs are and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: I don't want to do jsonStr.replace('"', '')  since I have "name": "John". That should not get replaced. Only double quotes inside the json value should get replaced Ex:  "name": "John"s" should become "name": "John's" or "name": "Johns". Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

With `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'(:\s+"[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*",)', r'\1', json_str)
re.sub(r'(:\s+"[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*",)', r'\1\"', json_str)
```

- `(:\s+"[^"]*)` matches the portion from last `:` to second `"` and put in captured group 1
- `"` matches literal `"`, and the zero width positive lookahead `(?=[^"]*",)` makes sure the match is followed by another `"`, immediately prior to `,`
- In the first replacement, only the captured group is kept; and in the second the captured group is followed by escaped `"` in the replacement

**Example:**

```
In [163]: json_str = '{"name": "John"s Garage", "company": "ABC"}'

In [164]: re.sub(r'(:\s+"[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*",)', r'\1', json_str)
Out[164]: '{"name": "Johns Garage", "company": "ABC"}'

In [165]: re.sub(r'(:\s+"[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*",)', r'\1\"', json_str)
Out[165]: '{"name": "John\\"s Garage", "company": "ABC"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` like so:

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])"([a-zA-Z])', r'\1\2', input);
```

This will preserve any letter characters around the quote, so it won't target a double quote with a space, comma, or colon after it, for example.

I see now that you tried something similar. The difference is the capture groups, and re-inserting them with `r'\1\2'`