# use regular expression to replace extra quote inside json

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I got an unexpected quote in my json string that make json.loads(jstr) fails.

```
json_str = '''{"id":"9","ctime":"2018-02-13","content":"abcd: "efg.","hots":"103b","date_sms":"2017-11-22"}'''
```

So I'd like to use the regular expression to match and delete the quote inside the value of "content". I tried something in [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817143/replace-double-quotes-inside-json-value-using-python):

```
import re
json_str = '''{"id":"9","ctime":"2018-02-13","content":"abcd: "efg.","hots":"103b","date_sms":"2017-11-22"}'''
pa = re.compile(r'(:\s+"[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*",)')
pa.findall(json_str)

[out]: []
```

Is there any way to fix the string?

Comment: Where is that "JSON" coming from? You'd be far better ensuring it's correctly escaped at the source.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @jonrsharpe, you'd be far better off cleaning the source.
That said, if you do not have control over where the extra quote is coming from, you could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` using the newer `regex` module and neg. lookarounds like so:

```
"[^"]+":\s*"[^"]+"[,}]\s*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<![,:])"(?![:,]\s*["}])
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/OePatv/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import json, regex as re

json_str = '''{"id":"9","ctime":"2018-02-13","content":"abcd: "efg.","hots":"103b","date_sms":"2017-11-22"}'''

# clean the json
rx = re.compile('''"[^"]+":\s*"[^"]+"[,}]\s*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<![,:])"(?![:,]\s*["}])''')
json_str = rx.sub('', json_str)

# load it

json = json.loads(json_str)
print(json['id'])
# 9
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I used:

```
whole = []
count = 0
with open(filename) as fin:
    for eachline in fin:
        pa = re.compile(r'"content":\s?"(.*?","\w)')
        for s in pa.findall(eachline):
            s = s[:-4]
            s_fix = s.replace("\"","")
            eachline = eachline.replace(s,s_fix)

        data = json.loads(eachline)
        whole.append(data)
```